# How to sort the hashmap in descending order by values and if the values are the same then by key in ascending order

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` named "relevance" e.g {2: 3, 1: 3, 3: 3, 5: 4, 4: 4, 6: 3} and I want do DESC sorting by values.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> sortedRelevance = new LinkedHashMap<>();
relevance.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Integer>comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
        .forEachOrdered(x -> sortedRelevance.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));
```

I get a hashmap {5: 4, 4: 4, 2: 3, 1: 3, 3: 3, 6: 3}. How can I sort ascending keys with the same values?

Comment: After sorting the map in descending order of the values, do you want to sort the map in ascending order of the keys? Please clarify your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "chain" Comparators by adding calls to [`thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing(java.util.Comparator)):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> sortedRelevance = new LinkedHashMap<>();
relevance.entrySet()
         .stream()
         .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Integer> comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                          .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
         .forEachOrdered(x -> sortedRelevance.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));
```